# How to config .htaccess HTTP_REFERER in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

in .htaccess I using code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule !check.php http://www.domain.com/check.php?url=http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

All Url from `domain.com` will redirect to `domain.com/check.php`, But I want when access link `domain.com/enter.php` will not redirect to `domain.com/check.php`, How to fix it?

Comment: Side note: in regular expressions, `.` is an operator that means *any character*. When you want a literal dot you need to escape it: `\.`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/enter.php$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/check.php?url=http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```